# String to Date in Android

Tags: android, date

i have a string which means a date. it looks like this :

`/Date(1448880305230+0200)/`

So how to convert it to Calendar or any type of date ?

Comment: Take a look at the manual:  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Looks like an epoch timestamp with a timezone offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string above in your question doesn't look like unixtime, but technically speaking you can use SimlpeDateFormat to format your date like this:

```
long unixSeconds = 1372339860;
// *1000 is to convert seconds to milliseconds
Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L); 
// the format of your date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"); 
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
//Log it in 
//System.out.println(formattedDate);
//Log.d(formattedDate);
```